# Plugin that lets user select focal point/cropped area

Tags: assets

I would like to let the editor of a specific entry select the focal point and cropped area each time she selects an asset for an asset field.

How can I achieve that?

I know about the built in focal point function in Craft CMS 3 that lets me edit one asset and set a focal point - but what I want is:

1. Let the user select focal point each time an asset is selected
2. If the asset field has a fixed aspect ratio, let the user select specifically which portion of the image should become the cropped version.

Like this:

[image: Description of how I would like the crop to be performed]

I found a plugin called [Ansel](https://buzzingpixel.com/software/ansel-craft/documentation), which seems to let me do what I want. My question is if there is another way - or built in way to achieve what I want?

Comment: I'll review this question again when I've tested out Ansel.

Answer (score 3):

With Craft CMS 3, focal points are built into the Image Editor.

> *To launch the Image Editor, double-click on an image (either on the Assets page or from an Assets field) and click on the “Edit” button in the top-right of the image preview area in the HUD. Alternatively, you can select an asset on the Assets page and then choose “Edit image” from the task menu (gear icon).*

[*more info*](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/assets.html#focal-points)

---

Here's how you could use the asset's focal point in your code:

```
Check if image has a user-defined focal point:
{% if image.hasFocalPoint %}

Get the focal point values:
{{ image.focalPoint.x }} / {{ image.focalPoint.y }}

Get the focal point values as CSS (e.g. for use in the object-position value):
{{ image.getFocalPoint(asCss=true) }}
```

---

I think in Craft CMS 2, these two plugins were widely used:

[Focal Point Field](https://github.com/aelvan/FocalPointField-Craft)
[Focus Point](https://github.com/smcyr/Craft-FocusPoint)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Please see the reworded question with an illustration. I know about the built in focal point functionality, but that doesn't seem to give me what I want.